# Full Disk Encryption and Dropbox

Tags: encryption, dropbox

I am considering to do a Full Disk Encryption on a fresh install.

1. the files that I store on the Dropbox folder, will be sent to Dropbox encrypted?
2. what if I plug an external unencrypted hard disk and I add a file to it, it would be encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the files that I store on the Dropbox folder, will be sent to Dropbox
>   encrypted?

No. When using full disk encryption the kernel will unencrypt the data and send it in plain to the dropbox daemon, it will then copy this unencrypted data to the cloud.

The second question is an obvious no, but you should probably ask it as a separate question.